# Maximize battery life while recording video

Tags: battery-life, video-recording

There are times where I need to record a lot of continuous video. I've found battery life to be insufficient for this. Is there anything I can do to squeeze out every bit of battery efficiency?

The biggest offender is probably the screen. I don't need it to be on, as the phone is usually propped up against something while I do the stuff I'm trying to record (weight lifting in my basement; recording myself to check for correct technique). Codec choice also comes to mind as potentially CPU intensive and thus battery draining.

Any ideas?

Comment: Power bank might be helpful.

Comment: Maybe connect it to a socket while recording?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no socket close enough for me to use. I will look into using a power bank, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Secret Eye](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tnavitech.hddenvideorecorder) can help the drain from screen. It allows to record even after the screen is switched off. There are lots of similar apps. Find the best one.

Inorder to save more battery,

1. You can root the phone and use an cpu governor to run the processor at lower clock cycle.
2. Freeze unwanted apps.
3. Turn off radio

Comment: By "turn off radio", I assume you mean "turn on airplane mode"? Thank you for pointing me at secret eye. That and a power bank can probably solve my problems.

Comment: Yes as turning off radio can save battery

Comment: I've tried a few "secret eye" apps, and they all seem to be a little too secret for my tastes. I'd like to know what I'm recording, and then be able to just turn the screen off to maximize battery life. I'm not interested in *actual* secret recording. Do you know of any apps that can do that?